# Flutter without Android and Chrome

Tags: flutter, dart, google-chrome

I am evaluating flutter and dart as a desktop ui framework. I am a bit bemused that, post-installation, flutter now wants me to install android sdk (!) and also chrome browser (!!). Neither of these is allowed (or otherwise useful) in my environment.

So, the question - can I set up flutter and develop desktop apps locally without installing android sdk/tools and chrome?

Comment: yes, you can ignore those message if you aren't intended to build for those platforms.